# How can I make WorldEdit ignore water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

Is there a way to like ignore water in WorldEdit? If you want to edit the terrain under deep water you will just edit the water instead.

I'm almost sure you can remove the water then edit the terrain then fill back to water but is that really the only choice?

I'm playing in Minecraft 1.16.1!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace near command to replace one type of block at a time.

---

The only downside of this is that you have to run it multiple times.